# MySQL: Avoid filesort when using IN and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, filesort

Let's suppose I have the following table (let's call it `my_table`):

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `table_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `my_field` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
   PRIMARY KEY  (`table_id`),
   KEY `my_field` (`my_field`,`table_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

The primary key for `my_table` is `table_id` (auto_increment) and I also have a key with `my_field` and `table_id`.

If I test this query...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_field = 28
ORDER BY table_id DESC;
```

... I get:

```
id  select_type  table     type  possible_keys  key       key_len  ref    rows  Extra
--- -----------  --------  ----  -------------  --------  -------  -----  ----  -----
1   SIMPLE       my_table  ref   my_field       my_field  8        const  36
```

You can see that it's using the correct key (`my_field`).

But if I try this...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_field IN (1, 28, 20)
ORDER BY table_id DESC;
```

... I get:

```
id  select_type  table     type  possible_keys  key     key_len  ref     rows  Extra
--- -----------  --------  ----  -------------  ------  -------  ------  ----  ---------------------------
1   SIMPLE       my_table  ALL   my_field       (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  406   Using where; Using filesort
```

You can see that it's not using any key at all, and worse, using **filesort**.

Even if I do "`FORCE INDEX (my_field)`", It still does the filesort.

Is there any way to avoid the filesort?

Comment: Updated my answer. A derived table might help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is my understanding that MySQL cannot use the index to sort this query.

MySQL can only use the index if it just happens to be sorted the same way as your query. Let's say that your records for `(table_id,my_field)` are

```
(1,1), (2,28), (3,14), (4,20)
```

An index on `(my_field,table_id)` would be stored like this

```
(1,1), (14,3), (20,4), (28,2)
```

When executing the query from your IN example *(for simplicity's sake, we'll say that your ORDER BY is ASCending)*, MySQL would find

```
(1,1), (20,4), (28,2)
```

...in this order. No matter what, it will have to sort those into `(1,1),(28,2),(20,4)`. That's the filesort. That's why MySQL could only use that index if the query was `ORDER BY my_field` or `ORDER BY my_field, table_id` because the index is already in this order. That's also why it cannot *[currently, some future version may allow you to sort composite indexes in mixed order]* use the index if you mix ASC and DESC. The index is sorted in ASC,ASC and no matter which way you read it, it won't be in the right order.

Note that **there's nothing wrong with "filesort"**, it's part of the normal execution of a query. It doesn't actually use files either and should be very fast.

If you have to sort thousands of rows, you may get better results by using a small derived table, especially if each row is really big (lots of fields, BLOBs, etc...)

```
  SELECT t.*
    FROM (
          SELECT table_id FROM my_table WHERE my_field IN (1, 28, 20)
         ) tmp
    JOIN my_table t USING (table_id)
ORDER BY t.table_id DESC
```

You will trade the filesort for a derived table. In some cases, it can be much more performant and in others, slightly less. YMMV

Comment: Well, filesort actually IS a problem when it's sorting a very large number of records. It's a shame that MySQL can't use indexes to sort this way.

Comment: good answer, but I will not agree that filesort is not a problem like @Boro says. If you need to sort many rows this will not be fast. If you need to sort 10 rows, than you don't need to waste time for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your keys are backwards in your SQL. Don't you want the primary key to be **`table_id`**?

This is probably what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `table_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `my_field` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
   PRIMARY KEY  (`table_id`),
   INDEX `my_index` (`my_field`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Comment: My mistake. The actual primary key is table_id. This table is a slimplified version of the actual table I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a mistaken "=" sign. Remove it like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_field IN (1, 28, 20)
ORDER BY table_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not use the key `my_field` because it is a key based on both `table_id` and `my_field`. If you are performing a query based on `my_field` alone, you have to have an index on `my_field` exclusively.

Having a single key on more than one column does not mean that if you search by any of the columns, that key is used. A particular key is used only when all the search columns in the query are also in the key.

Comment: I've just edited my question. The query uses my_field for the WHERE clause, and table_id for the ORDER BY clause, which are the two columns included in the my_field index, in the precise order for it to be MySQL friendly :)