# How to select last N Rows without using an Index

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a query that contains several conditions to extract data from a table of **5 million** rows. A composite index has been built to partially cover some of these conditions to the extend that I am not able to cover the sorting with an index:

```
SELECT columns FROM Table WHERE conditions='conditions' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT N;
```

The `id` itself is an `auto-increment` column. The above query can be very slow (**4-5s**) as `filesort` is being used. By removing the `ORDER BY` clause, I am able to speed up the query by up to 4 times. However the data extracted will be mostly old data.

Since post-processing can be carried out to sort the extracted data, I am more interested in extracting data from *roughly* the latest N rows from the resultset. My question is, is there a way to do something like this:

```
SELECT columns FROM Table WHERE conditions='conditions' LIMIT -N;
```

Since I do not really need a sort and I know that there is very high likelihood that the bottom N rows contain newer data.

Comment: Are you using a server side language to build your queries? You could run a query that just counts how many rows there are, and then use that number inside your limit.

Comment: @Brian Glaz: I am using PHP. Yes, I can do a count first. But wouldn't that double the time taken?

Comment: It would take more time, yes. But a simple `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table` usually runs pretty quickly.

Comment: @Brian Glaz, it has to check the conditions in the `where` clause first and that takes quite some time.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Keep in mind that there should be no problem in using ORDER BY with any indexed columns, including `id`.

```
SET @seq:=0;
SELECT  `id` 
FROM (

SELECT @seq := @seq +1 AS  `seq` ,  `id` 
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE `condition` =  'whatever'
)t1
WHERE t1.seq
BETWEEN (
(

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE `condition` =  'whatever'
) -49
)
AND (

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM  `Table` 
WHERE `condition` =  'whatever'
);
```

You can replace the "-49" with an expression like: -1 * ($quantity_desired -1);

Also check out this answer as it might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/725439/631764

And here's another one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441164/631764

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I have conditions in my `where` clause, but you don't.

Comment: Ok, check it out. It should work, but I still don't see why you can't just use ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 50

Comment: Thanks, but it looks complicated... What I need is simply to extract the latest N rows that satisfy `where` conditions. Here you are checking the condition three times. How does it translate to faster query speed?

Comment: I can, but it is slow due to `filesort`. If there is no `order by`, I can get the result much faster.

Comment: Queries are optimized. I tested the above on a table with 400,000 rows. It took a fraction of a second. The problem is that your request makes very little sense. You are asking us to come up with alternate way of doing something that is very simply done with SELECT ... ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT x.

Comment: Isn't your `id` a primary key? It should not be using filesort if you're ordering by any key field.

Comment: You can treat the conditions='conditions' AS condition_A='condition_A' AND condition_B='condition_B' AND condition_C='condition_C' AND condition_D='condition_D' AND condition_E='condition_E'... AND condition_Z='condition_Z'. As to why the alternate way, you may like to refer to the first paragraph of my question again. Sorry, if I sounded rude just now. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Yes, `id` is a primary key. But it couldn't be used due to the `where` clauses.

Comment: Well, I think you should at least try my query and see how it runs before you decide against it. What if it works?

Comment: Yes. Using my complex query with variables took 0.1791 second to get 50 rows out of ~315,000. ORDER BY DESC took 0.0005, so it was much faster. Still, I didn't have time to knit a sweater waiting for either query to complete.

Comment: Your `order by desc` may be running on index if you look at the query execution plan. Since your query took longer than normal, that won't be optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the last "few" rows using a between:

```
SELECT columns 
FROM Table 
WHERE conditions = 'conditions'
AND id between (select max(id) from table) - 50 AND (select max(id) from table)
ORDER BY id
DESC LIMIT N;
```

This example gets the last 50 rows, but the id index will be used efficiently. The other conditions and ordering will then be only over 50 rows. Should work a treat.

Comment: By doing that you are effectively throwing away 4,999,950 rows of data from the search analysis.

Comment: Yeah, this won't work because there could be 0 matching rows in the last 50. He needs the match to be performed first, and then take the last rows. See my revised answer.

Comment: @ButtleButkus But he said the matching rows are basically form the last few rows: *I am more interested in extracting data from roughly the latest N rows*

Comment: Yeah I know but I think he *meant* he wanted to extract the last N rows *of a resultset*. I.e. he always wants N rows. Your query can return 0 rows, because the subset of values BETWEEN (select max(id) from table) - 50 AND (select max(id) can have 0 overlap with the subset selected by the WHERE conditions.

Comment: @Bohemian: Sorry for causing the confusion. What I want is last N rows from the resultset. I will edit that.